# How to run WildFly-8.x with log4j2 & slf4j

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, log4j2, wildfly-8

I like to replace the standard logging mechanism in my `WildFly-8.x` with `log4j2`.

My idea of doing this was adding the following jars as modules:

```
log4j-api-2.3.jar
log4j-core-2.3.jar
```

and adding a `module.xml` to have the logger provided by the server.

Since I alredy use `slf4j` in my application, which is built via Maven, I decided to simply add the following stuff into my `pom.xml` for building my EAR-file

```
  <!-- versions are provided via private parent-pom -->
  <!-- slf4j-api -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- slf4j to log4j2, needed??? -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- log4j2 api, do I really need this??  -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- log4j2 api, do I really need this?? -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

So, a few questions remain:

1.) Do I need additional dependencies in my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, something that looks like this?

```
[...]
<ear-subdeployment-isolated>false</ear-subdeployment-isolated>
<deployment>
  <dependencies>
    [...]
    <!-- name taken from my introduced module.xml -->
    <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j2" slot="main" export="true" />
    [...]
  </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

2.) How do I configure log4j2 in my `standalone-*.xml`? I guess the `<loggers/>` and `<handlers/>` will only work with the built-in system?

3.) Do I need to specify the `pom.xml` snippet above into every maven module where I log something (which is nearly every module where a java class resides)?

And a little "candy" question:
4.) How do I setup log4j2 to compress logfiles, as it was done with log4j(1)-extras?

Comment: For compressing files you simply add the extension .zip or .gz to the log file name and it will be compressed respectively

Answer (score 2):

I hope [this](http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2014/09/alternative-logging-frameworks-for.html) link help you, it contains alternative logging framework for most of AS

and for your question 4

How do I setup log4j2 to compress logfiles, as it was done with log4j(1)-extras?

you can configure it like the below

```
filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz"
```

if you are using RollingFile  appender

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Unluckily it doesn't fully fulfill my needs, since I really want `Marker Support` in my logging.

Comment: A blog reference as an answer is not good. That website is currently down.